# Trouble setting an NSMutableDictionary inside of another NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I need to take information submitted by a user, store that information in an NSMutableDictionary, then store that NSMutableDictionary inside another NSMutableDictionary which is then encoded inside another class. For whatever reason, I can't seem to store the first NSMutableDictionary inside of the other.

I had to slim down the code that's in here due to work rules, so sorry if it seems to be missing anything. I only posted the parts that I'm having trouble with.

UserInfo.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyPlanInfo : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *emergencyDictionary;

@end
```

UserInfo.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyPlanInfo.h"

static NSString *emergencyDictionaryKey = @"emergencyDictionaryKey";

@implementation MyPlanInfo
@synthesize emergencyDictionary;

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super init];

    self.emergencyDictionary = [coder decodeObjectForKey:emergencyDictionaryKey];

    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:self.emergencyDictionary forKey:emergencyDictionaryKey];
}

@end
```

infoView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyPlanInfo.h"

@interface infoView : UIViewController <NSCoding>
{

    NSMutableDictionary *emergencyContactInfo;
    NSArray *userInfo;
    NSArray *userKeys;
    NSMutableArray *tempArray;    

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyPlanInfo *myPlanInfoObject;
-(void)saveUserInfo;
-(void)loadUserInfo;


@end
```

infoView.m:

```
#import "infoView.h"

@interface infoView ()

@end

@implementation infoView

static NSString *userInfoKey = @"userInfoKey";
static NSString *userName;
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
if(!self.myPlanInfoObject)
{
    self.myPlanInfoObject = [[MyPlanInfo alloc] init];
}

[self loadUserInfo];
}

-(void)addToDictionary
{
    emergencyContactInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:userInfo forKeys:userKeys];

    if([userInfo count] != 0 || userInfo == nil)
    {
        self.myPlanInfoObject.emergencyDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:emergencyContactInfo forKey:userName];
    }

    [self saveUserInfo];

}

- (void)saveUserInfo
{
    NSData *userInfoData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.myPlanInfoObject];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userInfoData forKey:userInfoKey];
}

- (void)loadUserInfo
{
    NSData *userInfoData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:userInfoKey];
    if(userInfoData)
    {
        self.myPlanInfoObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:userInfoData];
    }
}    
@end
```

In infoView.m, in the addToDictionary method, userInfo is an array of user inputted information, and userKey's is an array of key's. The emergencyContactInfo NSMutableDictionary works just fine, everything is in it, but when I try to set that as an object in a new NSMutableDictionary, for a key, it doesn't work. Everything is nil.

Anyone have any ideas on how what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: If you down vote, please leave a reason as to why so that I can avoid doing whatever I did wrong in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In the following line you’re creating an instance of `MyPlanInfo` using plain `alloc`/`init`:

```
self.myPlanInfoObject = [[MyPlanInfo alloc] init];
```

However, at least in the code provided, you haven’t overridden `init` in `MyPlanInfo`, but instead, `initWithCoder:`:

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super init];

    self.emergencyDictionary = [coder decodeObjectForKey:emergencyDictionaryKey];

    return self;
}
```

When you use just plain `init`, the `MyPlanInfo`’s `emergencyDictionary` instance variable will be `nil`. You should likely add something like the following to `MyPlanInfo` to override `init`:

```
- (id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
       emergencyDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

That will assure that the newly created `MyPlanInfo` instance has a proper `NSMutableDictionary` that can be manipulated from other classes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but it didn't seem to work. I am able to store other data types this way. For example, if I wanted to store an NSString from a UITextField, I can type `self.myPlanInfoObject.name = textField.text;` and it works just fine.

Comment: Good catch. I bet that's it. My advise on single-stepping through the code still stands though.